# Font size for some greek extended characters in true type fonts are 2 sizes bigger

Tags: fonts

I am a Ancient History student and, logically, I need to type in ancient greek, but  some greek characters for greek extended in true type fonts are 2 sizes bigger. For example, if I type "μοῖρα" in size 12, the character "ῖ" appears in size 14, though formally it says 12. If it is typed in 14, it will appear in 16, 18 in 20, and so on...

This does not happen with ubuntu fonts.
I've already reinstalled the fonts but the problem continues.

edit: I am using Times New Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce this (all of of my polytonic Greek letters are the right size), but this problem happens when the font doesn't have the particular glyph needed and defaults to a backup font to supply the glyph. Not all Unicode fonts have all the glyphs needed for a particular language. The larger size for one or two characters is common with Windows fonts when the missing glyph is pulled in from Tahoma or the equivalent.

You didn't mention the specific font you are using, but the solution is usually to find a specialized free font that is guaranteed to have all of the needed glyphs, such as [Galatia SIL](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fonts-sil-galatia) [image: Install GalatiaSIL] for polytonic Greek.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.

I am using Times New Roman.

Comment: A Microsoft font. Switching to another font should take care of it. If that works for you, please mark the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: The problem is that in my faculty (U. Lisbon, Faculty of Letters, Ancient History MA) I need to present the documents I produce in Times New Roman (eg. paper, reviews, etc...). If I save as pdf, it crystallizes the wrong sizes in the file. My workaround has been opening and formatting the file in Windows before sending it as a pdf or doc or odt. I do not think this is a long term solution if I am to convert fully to ubuntu though, and gimp+open office is all I need! 
Is there anyway to install the needed glyphs?
Thanks again!